# MySQL - Query to select all conversations with al least 2 not banned users

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I have this MySQL database schema: a user has many conversations and a conversation has many users (many to many association). So I have the table `users`, the table `conversations` and the join table called `participants` with the `user_id` and `conversation_id` fields (foreign keys).

Now I need to select all the conversations with at least 2 **not banned** users (users table has the `banned` boolean field).

Someone can help me to get the query to do this?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Any what's the problem?....

Comment: @Idris I need the query to select all conversations with al least 2 not banned users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM conversations c 
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.conversation_id 
            FROM participants p 
            INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id AND u.banned = 0
            GROUP BY p.conversation_id 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.user_id) >= 2 
          ) AS A ON c.conversation_id = A.conversation_id
```